# Why do I have to use conditional prob. and the total law of expectation? (Probability Generating Functions)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Imagine a branching process $Z_n$ such that
$$Z_n=\sum_{i=1}^{Z_{n-1}}X_i \text{ for even }n$$
$$Z_n=\sum_{i=1}^{Z_{n-1}}Y_i \text{ for odd }n,$$
where $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent copies of random variables $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

Let $W=\sum_{i=1}^YX_i$. Now we're supposed to compute PGF $G_W(s)$ to find the relationship between $G_W(s)$, $G_Y(s)$ and $G_X(s)$.

By first thought, which is incorrect, I did it like this:
$$G_W(s)=\mathbb{E}[s^W]=\mathbb{E}[s^{\sum_{i=1}^YX_i}]=\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^{Y}s^{X_i}]=\prod_{i=1}^{Y}\mathbb{E}[s^{X_i}]=G_X(s)^Y$$
The correct way of doing it looks like this:
$$G_W(s)=\mathbb{E}[s^W]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[s^W|Y]]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[s^{\sum_{i=1}^YX_i}|Y]]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^{Y}s^{X_i}|Y]]=\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^{Y}\mathbb{E}[s^{X_i}]]=\mathbb{E}[G_X(s)^Y]=G_Y(G_X(s))$$
This yields a different answer, which is the correct one. I can see why it is correct and it "feels more correct" than what I first did. But why exactly is that? Why do you have to use the total law of expectation and condition on Y? What falls in the first try? I don't really understand :(

Comment: I’m assuming that the first expectation, the one without conditioning on $Y$, is with respect to the joint distribution of each $X_i$. If that’s the case, then you are not averaging over $Y$, which means that the generating function is a deterministic function of $s$ and a random function of $Y$. If you average with respect to the joint distribution of each $X_i$ *and* $Y$, then the generating function is only a function of $s$, and this new expectation is the same one in the correct answer.